# Find number of ways to get number

Tags: combinatorics

I have a number that has odd number of divisors, for example 36, and I have all divisors of this number 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 18, 36. How many ways do we have to get 36 from divisors if we need to multiply k(from 2 to 1000 - for each k there is number of ways) any divisors? (repetition is allowed, order matters) For example, if k = 3: 1,6,6 - one way to get 36

Comment: If repetition is allowed, then there are infinitely many, because you can just write $p_1\times p_2\times 1\times 1\times 1\times... \times 1$, with as many $1$s as you want, where $p_1\times p_2 = 36$

Comment: but length of multiplication is limited - it might be different (2,3,4,5 but it is limited) If we have k = 3 then ways are (1,1,36)  (1,6,6)  (4,3,3)  (9,4,1)  (9,2,2) and so on. For each k we need to find the number of ways

Comment: Take the prime factorization, first.

Comment: Whoops, my bad! You're quite right, of course. I'll think on this question further

Comment: @H. sapiens rex , ok. So, I write some thoughts that I got - for 36 we got prime number 2^2 * 3^2. If we have k =3, we need somehow distribute our prime numbers among all positions, for example, 2, 2, 3^2 or 2^2, 3, 3 but we also have 1 as multiplier and here problems start

Comment: and we actually do not need to look at each combination because if k = 1000 then we have  huge number of combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each integer can be written as:
$$
p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_m^{a_m}
$$
$$
eg. 36=2^23^2
$$
where $p_1, p_2$ are prime numbers.
Each divisor is the product of these prime numbers, each raised to some power (from zero up to the maximum power allowed). Example, 9 is a divisor of 36, and it can be written:
$$
9=2^03^2
$$
So $p_1$ can be raised to the power from zero to $a_1$, $p_2$ can be raised to the power from zero to $a_2$ etc. The total number of divisors will be:
$$
(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_m)
$$
Since our number has odd number of divisors, that means that each of $(1+a_1), (1+a_2)$ etc is odd, so each of $a_1, a_2...a_m$ is even number.
Each "way" we are looking for can be written as:
$$
(p_1^{a_{11}}p_2^{a_{21}}...p_m^{a_{m1}}\ ,\ p_1^{a_{12}}p_2^{a_{22}}...p_m^{a_{m2}}\ ,...,\ p_1^{a_{1k}}p_2^{a_{2k}}...p_m^{a_{mk}})
$$
where
$$
a_{11}+a_{12}+...+a_{1k}=a_1
$$
$$
a_{21}+a_{22}+...+a_{2k}=a_2
$$
$$
...
$$
$$
a_{m1}+a_{m2}+...+a_{mk}=a_m
$$
The ways we can partition each $a_i$ to k number of non-positive integers (see Wikipedia, bars and stars) is given below. Note that zero is allowed as we can raise to the power of zero (see divisor 9 above).
$$
{a_i+k-1 \choose k-1}
$$
So the number of ways in our problem will be:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^m{a_i+k-1 \choose k-1}
$$
Example: 36 can be written as:
$$
36=2^23^2
$$
So the number of ways for k=3 will be (where $a_1=2$ and $a_2=2$):
$$
\prod_{i=1}^2{a_i+3-1 \choose 3-1}={4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}=6*6=36
$$

Comment: thank you for your solution. I would like to ask - how would it will be different if we have upper limit for each position? For example, limit is 9 then combination 1,6,6 is allowed but 1,1,36 is not

Comment: That would obviously depend on the upper limit. Having also an "random upper limit" condition seems a bit too loosely defined problem. Is this question given to you to solve, or it is your own thought?

Comment: it's given to me to solve, initially number that has odd number of divisors can be created with elements in range 1,n. Thus if we have n = 6 and k = 3 we can get 36 as product (1,6,6) but we can not get 36 by product (1,1,36) and we can not count combination (1,1,36) as acceptable

Comment: This is still not very clear to me, and in any case it seems like a different problem. You might want to post it as a new question (together with your attempts to solve it) and you can get proper answers (and not just trying to solve it in comments section).